# Hive: performance slowing down when using lower function

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive

I need to search for keywords, which is case insensitive. To do that, I'm using the below queries.
Logic wise okay, but performance drastically going down.

Table info

```
item_tbl: 558991075
keywords: 2000
```

```sql
SELECT itemname from items i
LEFT JOIN keywords k
ON i.id = k.item_id
AND lower(i.itemname) LIKE CONCAT('%', lower(k.value), '%')
WHERE l.item_id is null
```

Example:

```
    Keywords:
    Iphone x
    Yellow Mango
    Red onion
    
    Item names:
    Some Item 1
    Red color Iphone X
    Big Yellow Mango
```

The final valid item is `Some Item 1`.

Is there a way to improve this query performance?

Comment: I am not sure this is syntactically correct, could you be missing an 'AND' in this statement?

Comment: I think you are missing some table information it would definitely help to have more information to better help you.

Comment: [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097) [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [mre]

Comment: What do you mean, "the final item" & what is the significance of that one being it?

Answer (score 1):

What is likely taking the most time is the `like`.  If you are going to regularly use this query and it's not a one time thing you should try and precompute it. Or you should try to make this a straight forward join.

Is there a delimiter you can use to reduce the amount of items that you compare with `like`.  You basically have to compare every record to every other record when you use `like`.

- split i.itemname into 'words' something like `explode(split(i.itemname, ' ')) as words`
- split the k.value to get at least potential match largely reducing the words you evaluate
- join on 'words' matching `lower(split(k.value, ' ')[0]) = lower(words)`
- finally the actual match you wish to make `where lower(i.itemname) LIKE CONCAT('%', lower(k.value), '%')`

This would enable the power of a join to send the data to the right reducer and reduce the amount of comparisons.

Comment: I tried and it seems it's not working as expected. The reason is, the keywords table needs an exact match (case insensitive) with item_name. I've added an example in the question

Comment: I have further updated the answer to encompass the new information