# Which query is the fastest--the one using inner join or the one using a subquery?

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, query-optimization, inner-join

I have two queries giving me the same result. Which one is the most efficient?

The model:

```
Order {  
 orderId 
}

OrderItem {  
 orderItemId  
 orderId   
 productId 
}

Product {   
 productId 
}
```

The relationship between Order and OrderItem is one-to-many, and many OrderItems are related to one Product.

I'd like to retrieve the orders that are related to a specific product (in the requests the parameter :productId).

The first request with inner join:

```
Select distinct o
from Order o
inner join OrderItem oi
on o.id =
oi.orderId  and oi.productId = :productId
```

The second request with a count subquery in the where clause:

```
Select o 
from Order o
where 
    (Select count oi 
    from OrderItem oi 
    where oi.orderId = o.id and oi.productId = :productId
    ) > 0
```

I also use DB2 and Hibernate. And there is an index on each primary and foreign keys.

Comment: When you run them, which runs faster?

Comment: It’s an unanswerable question. It depends on the RDBMS you are using, the hardware you are running on, the data volume, indexing/partitioning, etc etc

Comment: Please include the execution plan of each query. Also, please include the existing indexes in both tables. I would guess the first query is easier to optimize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

Comment: [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)
[mre] [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097) [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932)

Comment: What is "theoretically"? What is "not theoretically"?

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own ways of interpreting and satisfying queries. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries aren't valid. You must say `SELECT column` rather than `SELECT table`. I assume you want this.

```sql
Select distinct o.id    -- COLUMN NAME here.
from Order o
inner join OrderItem oi
on o.id =
oi.orderId  and oi.productId = :productId
```

You want something straightforward: a set of ids from one table that meet a condition in a joined table. You could probably get this with a very simple one-table query.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT oi.orderId AS Id
FROM OrderItem oi
WHERE oi.productId = :productId
```

But, unless there's an enforced foreign-key constraint between oi.orderId and o.Id this might get you some extra orderIds: ones that exist in the OrderItem table but not in the Order table.

Your first example is a good way -- an ideal way, even -- to overcome that objection.

Your second example is not so good. It has a correlated subquery. That is, the subquery refers to a column in a table alias -- `o.id` -- from the outer query. That means it must potentially repeat the evaluation of the subquery for each row from the outer query. That *cannot* be faster than your first query, even with the smartest query planner in the galaxy.

Now, if instead you want all the columns of your `Order` table (`SELECT o.*`) matching the particular query in the second table, use this.

```sql
SELECT o.*
  FROM Order o
 WHERE o.Id IN (
          SELECT oi.orderId
            FROM OrderItem oi
           WHERE oi.productId = :productId
     )
```

That's the fastest way to retrieve entire rows from one table that match some criterion in another table. Notice that the `IN ()` operator automatically handles duplicate values.

**Pro tip** Use SELECT DISTINCT sparingly. If you find yourself using it on more than one column, you probably need to try to understand why you might have duplicates.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much. The queries I described are object queries, not standard sql, sorry. The one with the 'In' seems to be the best indeed, I guess the result of the subquery is saved, and if the algorithm uses a Hashtable for the comparison that's even better.

Comment: SQL is a *declarative language*. We tell it *what we want*, not *how to get it*. That's a tricky thing for typical procedural programmers to wrap our minds around.

Comment: Yes and behind the declaration, there are procedures, some better then the others 