# Slow query in SQL Server with LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, performance, left-join, query-optimization

I have the query below. When I use LEFT OUTER JOIN my query is very slow. It took more than 1 minute for the query to complete. Is there a way I can improve query speed while still using LEFT OUTER JOIN?

```
SELECT RISK.RA_HAZ_ID,
                    RISK.RA_CTRL_ID,
                    RISK.RA_HAZ_HAZARD_NAME,
                    RISK.RA_CTRL_CONTROL_NAME,
                    RISK.RA_CTRL_CONTROL_ID,
                    RISK.RA_IS_ESCALATED,
                    RISK.RA_IS_CONSEQUENCE,
                    RISK.RA_CTRL_OUTCOME,
                    RISK.RA_HAZ_IS_ALARP,
                    RISK.RA_HAZ_CONSEQUENCE,
                    RISK.RA_STEP_ORDER,
                    RISK.RA_STEP_NAME,
                    RISK.RA_HAZ_TYPE_NAME,
                    RISK.RA_CTRL_IS_REQUIRED,
                    RISK.RA_CTRL_IS_PRE_SELECTED,
                    RISK.RA_CTRL_IS_SELECTED,
                    RISK.RA_HAZ_SORT_ORDER,
                    RISK.RA_HAZ_COMMENT,
                    RISK.RA_CONTROL_COMMENT,
                    RISK.INIT_RISK,
                    RISK.RES_RISK,
                    RISK.RA_MATRIX_ID,
                    RISK.RES_RISK_LEVEL,
                    RISK.INIT_RISK_LEVEL,
                    MAX(RISK.RA_CTRL_ASSIGNED_FULL_NAME) AS RA_CTRL_ASSIGNED_FULL_NAME
FROM PRINT_RISK_ASSESSMENT_DETAILS RISK
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRINT_JSA_REFERENCE JSA ON JSA.OWNING_ACTIVITY_ID = RISK.OWNING_ACTIVITY_ID
WHERE JSA.ACTIVITY_ID = 10977 OR RISK.OWNING_ACTIVITY_ID = 10977
GROUP BY RISK.RA_HAZ_ID,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_ID,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_HAZARD_NAME,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_CONTROL_NAME,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_CONTROL_ID,
            RISK.RA_IS_ESCALATED,
            RISK.RA_IS_CONSEQUENCE,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_OUTCOME,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_IS_ALARP,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_CONSEQUENCE,
            RISK.RA_STEP_ORDER,
            RISK.RA_STEP_NAME,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_TYPE_NAME,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_IS_REQUIRED,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_IS_PRE_SELECTED,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_IS_SELECTED,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_SORT_ORDER,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_COMMENT,
            RISK.RA_CONTROL_COMMENT,
            RISK.INIT_RISK,
            RISK.RES_RISK,
            RISK.RA_MATRIX_ID,
            RISK.RES_RISK_LEVEL,
            RISK.INIT_RISK_LEVEL
  ORDER BY RISK.RA_STEP_ORDER,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_SORT_ORDER,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_HAZARD_NAME,
            RISK.RA_HAZ_TYPE_NAME DESC,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_IS_REQUIRED DESC,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_IS_PRE_SELECTED DESC,
            RISK.RA_CTRL_CONTROL_NAME
```

I want to improve query speed while still using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: That *huge* `GROUP BY` clause doesn't look right, if I am honest.

Comment: Try reading through [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), particularly through part about "If you're asking about query performance" and then edit this post so we can actually help you.

Comment: [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Before asking about SQL performance, research it & research asking about it. [ask] [Help] PS [mre]

Comment: [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097) [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932)

Answer (score 0):

You can first see if you have indexes over important fields `JSA.ACTIVITY_ID`, `JSA.OWNING_ACTIVITY_ID` and `RISK.OWNING_ACTIVITY_ID`. If not, consider creating it.

Since you are grouping over the entiry table, if `RISK` has an important amount of row, it will be slow.