# query timeout because of one always valid primary key condition in select mysql

Tags: mysql, select, timeout, where-clause, primary-key

I have a 40M record table having `id` as the `primary key`. I execute a select statement as follows:

```
select * from messages where (some condition) order by id desc limit 20;
```

It is ok and the query executes in a reasonable time. But when I add an always valid condition as follows, It takes a huge time.

```
select * from messages where id > 0 and (some condition) order by id desc limit 20;
```

I guess it is a bug and makes MySQL search from the top side of the table instead of the bottom side. If there is any other justification or optimization it would be great a help.

p.s. with a high probability, the results are found in the last 10% records of my table.

p.p.s. the `some condition` is like `where col1 = x1 and col2 = x2` where col1 and col2 are indexed.

Comment: Do you see the same effect if you replace `id > 0` with `1 = 1`?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the difference in query plans.

Comment: You know it's "always valid". Does the DBMS? What did you tell it, that it would know that? PS Debug questions require a [mre]. Good questions "show research effort". [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097)

Comment: If the "valid condition" is a `MATCH`, then all sorts of different issues arise.  So... Please provide the actual condition.

Comment: @RickJames I edited the post and provided some explanations on `some condition`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has to choose whether to use an index to process the `WHERE` clause, or use an index to control `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...`.

In the first query, the `WHERE` clause can't make effective use of an index, so it prefers to use the primary key index to optimize scanning in order by `ORDER BY`. In this case it stops when it finds 20 results that satisfy the `WHERE` condition.

In the second query, the `id > 0` condition in the `WHERE` clause can make use of the index, so it prefers to use that instead of using the index for `ORDER BY`. In this case, it has to find *all* the results that match the `WHERE` condition, and then sort them by `id`.

I wouldn't really call this a bug, as there's no specification of precisely how a query should be optimized. It's not always easy for the query planner to determine the best way to make use of indexes. Using the index to filter the rows using `WHERE id > x` could be better if there aren't many rows that match that condition.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. It makes sense. But is it true that database engine use just one index to scan the results?

Comment: MySQL is pretty limited in that respect. Read [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: MySQL uses one index per table reference, mostly. There are exceptions like [index merge optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html), but somehow that feature doesn't kick in as often as you might think it should.

Comment: Great answer, could you help to show me where to find short documents about how mysql choosing indexes, like you said in the first sentence?

Comment: See the link in my second comment.

Answer (score 0):

A query like this

```
select  *
    from  messages
    where  col1 = x1
      and  col2 = x2
    order by  id desc
    limit  20;
```

is best handled by a 'composite' index with the tests for '=' first:

```
INDEX(col1, col2, id)
```

Try it, I think it will be faster than either of the queries you are working with.

Answer (score -1):

It’s not a bug. You are searching through a 40 million table where your where clause doesn’t have an index. Add an index on the column in your where clause and you will see substantial improvement.

Comment: But it shouldn't search the entire table, because it should use the `ORDER BY` to search it in the order of the indexed `id` column, and stop when it gets 20 results.

Comment: That's what it does in the original query without `id > 0` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Dear @Ranabir Dey, as I wrote, the search process is fine just without id>0 and I managed the necessary indices before.