# Joining with a json column makes the result very slow

Tags: mysql, database-design, query-optimization, database-normalization

There are 3 tables and I linked three tables with one query. But the problem is that the result returns in 7-8 seconds. One of the columns I join is JSON type and the data in it is json. For this reason, I did the join process with JSON. How can I make the following query faster? Or can I achieve the same result using another method?

Here is a table example for sales with json column:

[sales table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKx05.png)

And the query:

```sql
SELECT
    `s`.`id` AS `id`,
    `s`.`status` AS `status`,
    group_concat(`c`.`display_name` separator ', ') AS `buyer`,
    `u`.`display_name` AS `partner`,
    `s`.`sales_price` AS `sales_price`,
FROM `sales` AS `s`
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `u` ON (`u`.`id` = `s`.`user_id`)
JOIN `contacts` AS `c` ON (json_contains(`s`.`buyers`, concat('"', `c`.`id`, '"')))
GROUP BY
    `s`.`id`
```

My tables:

SALES

| column_name | column_type |
| --- | --- |
| id | integer |
| buyers | varchar(255) |
| user_id | integer |
| status | integer |
| sales_price | double(13,2) |

CONTACTS

| column_name | column_type |
| --- | --- |
| id | integer |
| display_name | varchar(255) |

USERS

| column_name | column_type |
| --- | --- |
| id | integer |
| display_name | varchar(255) |

SALES.user_id => USERS.id
SALES.buyers => CONTACTS.id

Sales.buyers can be multiple or single like this:

If the sale has one contact: ["774"] or
If the sale has two contacts: ["774", "854"]

I want to see this output:

| S.id | S.status | C.display_name AS BUYER | U.display_name AS PARTNER | S.sales_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Michael Owen | David Beckham | 199999 |
| 2 | 1 | Ariel Ortega, Mauro Icardi | Leo Messi | 219000 |
| 3 | 0 | Nicholas Anelka, Didier Drogba | Thierry Henry | 710000 |

EXPLAIN result is here:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 12455638 |  |
| 2 | DERIVED | s | ALL |  |  |  |  | 857 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 2 | DERIVED | u | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | s.user_id | 1 |  |
| 2 | DERIVED | c | ALL |  |  |  |  | 14533 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
| 3 | UNION | s2 | ALL | buyers_index |  |  |  | 857 | Using where |
| 3 | UNION | u2 | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | s2.user_id | 1 |  |
|  | UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure and the execution plan for that query

Comment: ``JOIN `contacts` AS `c` ON (json_contains(`s`.`buyers`, concat('"', `c`.`id`, '"')))`` - for starter, i'd question myself if i have to use json or just go with the good old one-to-many through foreign keys.

Comment: Please share the execution plan of your query

Comment: "EXPLAIN result is here: https://pastebin.com/PCvsiuRP" - please add it **directly** to your question, not to any external ressource. Also, please use the common tabular format, not `FORMAT=JSON`

Comment: Ok @Nico Haase, i added it directly to my post.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link. [ask] [Help]

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) 
[Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097) etc etc

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/3404097)

Comment: From my perspective your question is quite good (after you added some details). I hope to see more contributions from you here, @grudge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified the source of your performance trouble as the arrays  of `contacts.id` values you store in your `sales.status` columns, in your case using the JSON format. SQL truly does not work well with data designs containing arrays in columns, whether JSON, comma-separated lists, or whatever.

Specifically, your `ON (json_contains(s.buyers, concat('"', c.i, '"')))` condition cannot exploit any index -- it isn't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) -- so it's inherently slow.

It looks like you have a [many-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) between rows of `sales` and `contacts`. The SQLish way to express that is with a *junction table*. You might call it `sales_buyers`. It will contain rows like this.

```
sales_id   contact_id
   1       774
   2       774
   2       854
```

These sample rows mean `sales.id` 1 has a single buyer, `contact.id` 774.  `sales.id` 2 has two buyers, 774 and 854.

Once you have that kind of junction table you can change your query to look like this:

```sql
...
FROM sales AS s
LEFT JOIN users AS u    ON u.id = s.user_id
JOIN sales_buyers AS sb ON s.id = sb.sales_id
JOIN contacts AS c      ON sb.contact_id = c.id 
...
```

(Notice also that you need `GROUP BY s.id, u.display_name` for your query to be correct.)

Your junction table will have this definition.

```sql
CREATE TABLE sales_buyers (
    sales_id INT NOT NULL,
    contact_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sales_id, contact_id),
    INDEX contact_sales (contact_id, sales_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This table definition has indexes going both ways. That helps queries be faster whether you start with `contacts` or `sales`.

You create a sales - to - buyer relationship by INSERTing a row into this table, and remove a relationship by DELETEing the row.

**Pro tip** Skip the backticks. Don't use reserved words for column or table names and you don't need them. And they just make SQL harder to type and to read.