# How do I improve the speed of this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join

I have two systems communicating with one another using send-acknowledge design where system 1 sends a record over to system 2 to be processed and once system 2 processes the message it will send an acknowledge message over to system 1 which changes the status from Pending -> Completed.

For example, at 1pm

**Pending Records Table @ 1pm:**

| Record_Seq | Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Pending |
| 2 | A | Pending |
| 3 | B | Pending |
| 4 | B | Pending |
| 5 | C | Pending |
| ... |  |  |
| 1000 | Z | Pending |

**Acknowledge Records Table @ 1pm:**

| Ack_seq | Type | Record_Seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null |

No acknowledge message received from system 2.

---

**Acknowledge Records Table 1.05pm:**

| Ack_seq | Type | Record_Seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 3 |
| 3 | B | 4 |
| 4 | A | 2 |
| 5 | C | 5 |
| ... | ... |  |

**Pending Records Table @ 1.05pm:**

| Record_Seq | Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Completed |
| 2 | A | Completed |
| 3 | B | Completed |
| 4 | B | Completed |
| 5 | C | Completed |
| ... |  |  |
| 1000 | Z | Pending |

---

The problem is that sometimes system 2 does not send over the acknowledged record so records could be left pending even though they were already processed.

I wrote the following to query to try to find the records that were missing their acknowledge

```
-- Since total number of pending records must equal the total number of acknowledge records,
-- The query counts and check for each type of pending records and joins it with the count of each type of ack record

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TYPE, COUNT(1) AS NUMBER_OF_PENDING FROM PENDING_RECORDS_TABLErecords
        WHERE TYPE IN (SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM PENDING_RECORDS_TABLE) 
        AND STATUS = 'PENDING'
        GROUP BY TYPE 
) AS RECORDS_SENT

LEFT JOIN -- SO THAT I CAN GET RECORDS THAT DID NOT RECEIVE ANY ACK AT ALL

(SELECT TYPE, COUNT(1) AS NUMBER_OF_RECEIVED FROM ACKNOWLEDGE_RECORDS_TABLE 
    WHERE TYPE IN (SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM PENDING_RECORDS_TABLE)
    GROUP BY TYPE
 ) AS ACK_RECEIVED
 
 ON (RECORDS_SENT.TYPE = ACK_RECEIVED.TYPE) 
 
 WHERE RECORD_SENT.NUMBER_OF_PENDING <> ACK_RECEIVED.NUMBER_OF_RECEIVED
 
 ORDER BY TYPE
```

1. The issue with this query is that it runs very slowly and if the distinct number of types > 100, it becomes exceedingly slow. How do I optimise the query so that it can run considerably faster? (Note: the size of the records and ack table are quite large)
2. I also encounter an issue where the query without the " WHERE RECORD_SENT.NUMBER_OF_PENDING <> ACK_RECEIVED.NUMBER_OF_RECEIVED" clause runs significantly faster than the query with this clause. I am not too sure what is causing the query to slow down because of this clause?

Comment: You `LEFT JOIN` to your derived table `ACK_RECEIVED` but `NUMBER_OF_RECEIVED` *must* have a non-`NULL` value, which isn't possible when no row is found. Is it intentional that you have an implicit `INNER JOIN`? If so, why not change it to an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Also, the `DISTINCT` operator in your `IN` subqueries isn't needed. `1` is in both `1,2,3` and `1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3`. The `DISTINCT` may actually cause the query to be slower, as `DISTINCT` can be quite an expensive operator. The data engine *might* be "smart" enough to ignore the `DISTINCT` operator, but then again, it might not be.

Comment: For performance question we need at a minimum: the tables and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. The question is not answerable otherwise.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) 
[mre] [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097)

Answer (score 2):

> ... query to try to find the records that were missing their acknowledgement

I suspect that you are overcomplicating things here.

This reads like `exists`. This query gives you the list of records showing as pending in the first table while they have an acknowledgement in the second table:

```
select *
from pending_records_table p
where status = 'PENDING'
  and not exists (
    select 1 
    from acknowledge_records_table a 
    where a.type = p.type and a.record_seq = p.record_seq
  )
```

The following index would be beneficial for this query: `acknowledge_records_table(type, record_seq)`.

If you wanted to aggregate this resultset by type:

```
select type, count(*) as cnt
from pending_records_table p
where status = 'PENDING'
  and not exists (
    select 1 
    from acknowledge_records_table a 
    where a.type = p.type and a.record_seq = p.record_seq
  )
group by type
order by type
```