# Is there an alternative to rank() over(partition by...order by)

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I'm trying to change the rank() over (partition by...order by...) in the subquery into a group by and min/max since the rank() is causing the query performance to be slow. This is because after the subquery goes through partitioning each row it then ranks it. I just want the first working date of each applicant without having to go through the ranking and partitioning.

I have commented out the original parts of the query to show what I have tried.

1. I have included `join applicants_cte apps on apps.person_key = apps.person_key` to replace the where clause with a subquery select in it.
2. Group by all the fields being selected. I wanted to replace the `partition by ap.person_id`   into a `group by ap.person_id` so that I don't have to partition each row of data.
3. I included `min(ap.working_date)` to replace the `order by ap.work_date asc`.

These steps have given me the expected count output (1,500,000) but once I removed the `select * (from (select rank() over (partition by ap.person_id order by ap.working_date asc)` I got a really big count output (34,000,000).

```
with applicants_cte as 
    (select person_key
    from applicants.people
    where date is between '01-01-2022' and '01-01-2023'
    group by person_key
    )
    ,
list_of_applicants as 
    -- Removed subquery and rank()
    /*
    (select *
    from (select rank() over (partition by ap.person_id order by 
        ap.working_date asc) list,
    */
    (select min(ap.working_date),
        ap.person_id
        date(applicants.start_date) as start_date,
        a.first_name,
        a.last_name,
        b.email_address
    from applicants.people ap
    join information a on a.person_key = ap_id_key
    join contact_information b on b.person_info_id = ap.id_key
    -- replaced where statement with join 
    join applicants_cte apps on apps.person_key = apps.person_key
    where date(applicants.start_date) IS NOT NULL
    /*
    where date(applicants.start_date) IS NOT NULL
    and ap.person_id in (select applicant_id 
        from applicants_cte)) c
    where c.list = 1
    */
    group by ap.person_id,
        start_date,
        a.first_name,
        a.last_name,
        b.email_address
    ) 
select count(*) from list_of_applicants
```

Comment: Have you imvestigated providing an index to support the ordering for the Rank window function?

Comment: Does `select count(distinct person_id)` give you the correct value? I haven't really trudged through that query, but I would think you could just use a CTE to get their start date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With respect, it's difficult to infer either your output requirement or the structure of your tables from your question. When I personally get into a snarl like your query shows (I do often), I take a step back and reason from first principles: I have this data and I want that answer.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) 
[mre] [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097)

Comment: This code does not parse (no `with`;`is`; `ap.person_id date(applicants.start_date)`) including in comments code (`(select ... from applicants_cte)) c where c.list = 1`). It's not clear what your original query was or what exact code goes with what bullet & what exact things you tried & what happened with each.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a DISTINCT to my first CTE `applicants_cte` and I split my second CTE `list_of_applicants` into two subqueries.