# Mysql sub query so slow

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

**Main query schema:**

```
  `idno` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `type` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `fullname` text,
  `telno` varchar(13) default NULL,
  `tin` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `encoded_by` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idno`)
```

**The subquery inside my main query:**

```
SELECT 
count(IF(source='L',1,NULL)) as L,  
count(IF(source='B',1,NULL)) as B, 
count(IF(source='M',1,NULL)) as M 
FROM table_view_name WHERE idno=main_query.idno
```

What is a faster subquery?

Comment: Depends on what your table looks like. You should add the schema and some sample data to your question.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) 
[mre] [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097)

Comment: If that is a subquery, we need to see it the main query.  Also need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what indexes (etc) you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sum function instead of count to optimize the query :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(source='L') as L,  
    SUM(source='B') as B, 
    SUM(source='M') as M 
FROM table_name 
WHERE tax_idno=main_query_id;
```

and make sure you have proper indexing on 'source' and 'tax_idno'

Comment: @HerbertYeo Since we still don't know how the table actually looks like, it's hard to judge. but I did a test over 1 million rows and it's actually slower than your query.

Comment: You mean a "composite" `INDEX(tax_idno, source)`, not two separate indexes.