# Optimizing inner Join SQL Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, inner-join

I have two tables T1 and T2.

```
select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c 
from T1 t1 
inner join T2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c
```

T1 has 2 million rows and T2 has 4 million.

`explain analyse` of the query / execution time takes approximately 30 seconds.

I have indexes for the column c on T1 and T2.

I do not need to select columns from T2.

What can I do to improve this?

What is an alternate way of writing this query?

Query plan:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for all tables and indexes and the query plan for your query ?

Comment: How often are you going to run this query that you care if it takes 3 seconds?

Comment: The query has no filtering condition. It's reading the whole table(s), that is 2 + 4 = 6 million rows. I would not complain with a three second response time.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) 
[mre] [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/266284)

Comment: When one inserts an image using the site editor image button it makes a site copy & inserts text to show an image inline with hidden alt text that one types instead of the placeholder alt text. When a user doesn't have enough reputation to inline an image the alt text is shown instead. The alt text is for screen readers & should describe the image content. Unfortunately few posters give it correctly. Here the image doesn't belong though.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not need to select columns from T2.

Why then the join? Do you want to duplicate all t1 rows by the number of matching t2 rows? If this is not the case and you merely want to select t1 rows where a match in t2 exists, then use `EXISTS` (or `IN` if you like that better).

```
select a, b , c
from t1
where exists (select null from t2 where t2.c = t1.c);
```

or

```
select a, b , c
from t1
where c in (select c from t2);
```

For the DBMS these two queries would ideally be considered equal and thus lead to the same execution plan, although to the human reader it looks like in the first query we want to loop through all t2 rows and look up their c in t2, while in the second query we suggest that we get a set of Cs from t2 that we then use to quickly find the matching rows in t1. This is what SQL is about. It is a declarative language, where we tell the DBMS what we want to see and not really care about how the DBMS will achieve this. This means the DBMS can decide to loop through t1 and then look up t2 or do it vice versa or find a completly different approach, e.g. by building buckets to collect rows, with either query.

What we can do is provide indexes for the loops we have in mind. The DBMS will use one index or the other or none at all. We can check this an drop the unused index(es) again.

```
create index idx1 on t1 (c) include (a, b);
create index idx1 on t2 (c);
```

You say, you already have indexes on t1(c) and t2(c). Maybe the re-written queries help the optimizer to get to an optimal execution plan. Or maybe the first index, which is a coverng index because of the include clause, speed things up a little. Or maybe your query is already about as fast as it can get.

Comment: I've tried exists and in clauses, they both result in similar time as my join, although exists seem to be slightly better, thanks

Comment: If you really only pick values from `T1`, these are the smarter choice because of the `inner join`'s pointless duplication of rows with multiple matches. [Here's how they compare](https://dbfiddle.uk/kLcIlec1) (note unequal `rows=33472` for the join and `rows=28423` for exists). If your schema dictates there's always at most one match, then it won't matter, although these still win by having higher optimisation potential in general (the semi-join, later in the demo).

Answer (score -1):

That heavily depends on the [characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data#Characteristics) of the data and traffic on the tables. Before you share your table and index definitions along with a `explain (analyze,buffers,verbose)` output, guessing purely based on your mention of basic, single-column index aiding the operation: you could look into tuning some additional settings of those indexes.

I'm assuming you're already getting an [index-only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) on `t2` and a regular index scan on `t1`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kLcIlec1)

```sql
create table t1(a text, b text, c int);
insert into t1 select gen_random_uuid(),gen_random_uuid(),random()*1e6
from generate_series(1,2e6,1)_(n);
create index t1_c_idx on t1(c);
vacuum analyze t1;

create table t2(a text, b text, c int);
insert into t2 select gen_random_uuid(),gen_random_uuid(),random()*1e7
from generate_series(1,4e6,1)_(n);
create index t2_c_idx on t2(c);
vacuum analyze t2;

explain (analyze,buffers,verbose)
select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c 
from T1 t1 
inner join T2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c;
```

```
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=44.65..218570.14 rows=2744902 width=78) (actual time=2.904..2532.031 rows=797062 loops=1)
   Output: t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
   Merge Cond: (t1.c = t2.c)
   Buffers: shared hit=2857658
   ->  Index Scan using t1_c_idx on public.t1  (cost=0.43..153103.24 rows=2000000 width=78) (actual time=0.009..1716.516 rows=2000000 loops=1)
         Output: t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
         Buffers: shared hit=2003982
   ->  Index Only Scan using t2_c_idx on public.t2  (cost=0.43..315262.71 rows=3999961 width=4) (actual time=0.018..543.618 rows=851437 loops=1)
         Output: t2.c
         Heap Fetches: 851437
         Buffers: shared hit=853676
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=12
 Planning Time: 0.194 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 5
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.411 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.199 ms, Emission 2.570 ms, Total 3.181 ms
 Execution Time: 2561.986 ms
```

The 2.5s above is close to your current score. If you [`include`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6) the other two columns you're fetching as payload on the index, you can get it to run index-only scans for *both* tables (finds everything in the indexes, doesn't have to jump to actual tables) - in my case that gives a **>4x speedup down to 0.6s**:

```sql
drop index t1_c_idx; 
create index t1_c_idx on t1(c)include(a,b);
analyze t1;
drop index t2_c_idx; 
create index t2_c_idx on t2(c)include(a,b);
analyze t2;

explain (analyze,buffers,verbose )
select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c 
from T1 t1 
inner join T2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c;
```

```
                                                                    QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=3.21..177965.47 rows=2549607 width=78) (actual time=1.162..536.684 rows=797062 loops=1)
   Output: t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
   Merge Cond: (t1.c = t2.c)
   Buffers: shared hit=299842
   ->  Index Only Scan using t1_c_idx on public.t1  (cost=0.43..122364.43 rows=2000000 width=78) (actual time=0.034..193.624 rows=2000000 loops=1)
         Output: t1.c, t1.a, t1.b
         Heap Fetches: 0
         Buffers: shared hit=22992
   ->  Index Only Scan using t2_c_idx on public.t2  (cost=0.43..244611.84 rows=3999961 width=4) (actual time=0.011..106.730 rows=851437 loops=1)
         Output: t2.c, t2.a, t2.b
         Heap Fetches: 0
         Buffers: shared hit=276850
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=12
 Planning Time: 0.180 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 3
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.243 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.109 ms, Emission 0.940 ms, Total 1.292 ms
 Execution Time: 565.847 ms
```

If your data is completely static or only refreshed/reloaded in full, you can also compact the indexes: by default they leave [10% empty space](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#INDEX-RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR) to accommodate incoming rows, which those tables don't need.

```
create index t1_c_idx on t1(c)include(a,b)with(fillfactor=100);
```

If heap fetches are unavoidable or your payload is too big, you can consider [`cluster`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html):

```
cluster t1 using t1_c_idx;
```